# How to disable Git auto-detecting email address?

Tags: git

On my desktop, if I don't explicitly set the user and email for a repository, git will throw an error saying it was unable to auto-detect my email address and will stop my commit. Given I work on a number of different repositories and want different author/email settings for each, I quite like this functionality.

I know this happens because my user/email is not configured. I am not asking how to resolve this error. Instead, I would like to know if it is possible, and if so how, to configure git to never auto-detect my email address?

On my laptop it does auto-detect. I then configure my user/email but then have to amend my commit. I would like it to reject my commit if I have not configured my user/email.

Comment: Simply you want it to ask your username and password every time you push or pull?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon I want to be required, once per repository, to manually configure my user and email and not have git attempt to auto-detect it so that all commits are rejected until I have configured those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `user.useConfigOnly` to true. (Assuming git >=2.8)

This will make git error out if no name or email are configured.

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!